# CMake - Installing issues to make package

Tags: python, c++, macos, qt, cmake

For installing dlib, I followed this tutorial : http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/03/27/how-to-install-dlib/.
I am on Mac OS X 10.12.5 and using Python 3.5.
I run

```
$ brew install cmake
$ brew install boost
$ brew install boost-python --with-python3
```

It works without any error.
But when I try to install dlib with pip install dlib. I have an error :

```
The C compiler
    "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc"
    is not able to compile a simple test program.
error: cmake configuration failed

ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/opt/qt/lib' for architecture x86_64
```

For the full error, please see on this link (doesn't want to paste the full error) :
https://gist.github.com/alexattia/3e98685310d90b65031db640d3ea716a

After retracing the error, when I tried to make dlib manually, I have this :

```
  Linking C executable cmTC_05e45

  /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/3.8.2/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_05e45.dir/link.txt --verbose=1


  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/cc
  -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names
  /usr/local/opt/qt/lib CMakeFiles/cmTC_05e45.dir/testCCompiler.c.o -o
  cmTC_05e45
```

For the full trace expand : https://gist.github.com/alexattia/1e54ffb87c9eb4c811033f5cadd90331

I reinstalled XCode (from Apple Store) and CMake (3.8.2 from the downloaded page), I even installed Qt Creator to have a clean version of Qt, but I still have the same error.
I tried to install it with conda but after the installation, I still don't have the module in python.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: And your *specific* question is - what?

Comment: How can I do to fix this an to install dlib ?

Comment: Key error line in your log is `ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/opt/qt/lib' for architecture x86_64` (that is, this line should be **in the question post** itself). Someone passes directory `/usr/local/opt/qt/lib` to the linker and linker treats it as a file for link with. Probably,  you have environment variable which specifies that.

Comment: I edited my post to add the line. Indeed, in my `.bash_profile`, I have 
`export LDFLAGS="/usr/local/opt/qt/lib"`, 
`export CPPFLAGS="/usr/local/opt/qt/include"`,
`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/qt/bin:$PATH"`. 
But even while commenting it, I still have the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You commented:

> Indeed, in my .bash_profile, I have export LDFLAGS="/usr/local/opt/qt/lib", 
>   export CPPFLAGS="/usr/local/opt/qt/include", export PATH="/usr/local/opt/qt/bin:$PATH".
>   But even while commenting it, I still have the same error

Neither of your assignments to `LDFLAGS` or `CPPFLAGS` makes sense, and the
first one is the cause the linker failure that concerns you.

The value of the environment variable `LDFLAGS`, if set, is interpreted by your build system
as linkage options. Likewise The value of the environment variable
`CPPFLAGS`, if set, is interpreted as preprocessor options.

`/usr/local/opt/qt/lib` is not a linkage option and `/usr/local/opt/qt/include`
is not a preprocessor option. These are simply directory names. Any argument that
you pass to the linker (or preprocessor, or compiler) that is not an option is
interpeted by the tool as an input file. Thus you have led the linker to believe
that `/usr/local/opt/qt/lib` is an input file to your linkage.

```
ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/opt/qt/lib' for architecture x86_64
```

is what the linker says when it discovers that `/usr/local/opt/qt/lib` is not
a file at all.

Presumably, you wish to instruct the linker that `/usr/local/opt/qt/lib` is
a directory in which it should search for libraries required by your linkage.
The linkage option that expresses that intent is:

```
-L/usr/local/opt/qt/lib
```

Here are the [GCC options for linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

Similarly you intend to instruct that preprocessor that `/usr/local/opt/qt/include`
is a directory in which it should search for header files. The preprocessor
option to express that is:

```
-I/usr/local/opt/qt/include
```

Here are the [GCC options for preprocessing](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options)

It is abnormal and inadvisable to specify compilation or linkage options
in your bash login profile, as you are doing. Specify such options in the
build system's input files (makefile, cmakelists file or similar), or as arguments to
the build system's configuration. But if you insist on specifying them in
your bash login profile, then you should specify:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/qt/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/qt/include
```

And once you have made these environment settings in your `bash_profile` they will
only take effect in new login shells.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanations. It worked!
You said : "It is abnormal and inadvisable to specify compilation or linkage options in your bash login profile, as you are doing." What's advisable? How can I find the input file to use in the profile?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but found out it was due to boost.

Try this.

```
  brew uninstall boost-python
  brew uninstall boost
  brew install boost-python --with-python3 --without-python
  pip3 install dlib
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. I still have the same error.
`ld: can't map file, errno=22 file '/usr/local/opt/qt/lib' for architecture
      x86_64`